# where statement doesn't work in stored procedure

Tags: mysql

So i have this stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`%` PROCEDURE `GetGoalDetail`(IN goalId int)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

SELECT *
FROM actions  
Where GoalId = goalId;

Select * From contributors 
where GoalId = goalId;

Select * From discussions 
where GoalId = goalId;
END
```

and when I call it:

```
CALL 'GetGoalDetail`(15);
```

I hope to see everything related to goalId = 15. But the second query always returns all of the contributors!!! Why is this? Is there some I am missing?

Comment: SP? Oh, stored procedure.

Comment: What happens if you rename your input parameter to `gId`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your paramter name is the same as your table fieldname, which means MySQL is NOT using your parameter:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`%` PROCEDURE `GetGoalDetail`(IN goalId int)
                                                        ^^^^^^----this

SELECT *
FROM actions  
Where GoalId = goalId;
      ^^^^^----^^^^^^--- which of those two is the field, and which is the parameter?
```

Since there's no way for mysql to know that you're attempting to do `fieldname = parameter`, it's just interpreting it as `fieldname = fieldname`, or essentially no where clause at all.

Try renaming your parameter to something else, that isn't present in any of your tables, like "foobar" or whatever.